# NodeJs Forever doesnt really start my app

Tags: node.js

I run my app using this command line

```
forever start app.js
```

It throws a warning message

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

It doesnt really start my app

Comment: ...and if you call the app with `node app`, what happens?

Comment: it will run and it doesnt display any error. but whenever i close the shell. my app will stop, as normal as it be

Comment: It looks like it is started, it is just displaying the warnings about those parameters not being set. What happens if you run `forever list`. Is app.js displayed there?